# Synapse suddenly started having problem about having hash distribution column in a Merge

Tags: merge, azure-synapse

I started geting error at 06-25-2022 in my Fact table flows. Before that there was no problem and nothing has changed.

The Error is:
Operation on target Fact_XX failed: Operation on target Merge_XX failed: Execution fail against sql server. Sql error number: 100090. Error Message: Updating a distribution key column in a MERGE statement is not supported.

Comment: Hi - so what’s your actual question? The error message seems reasonably clear - have you identified your distribution key column(s) and is your merge statement updating it/them?

Comment: Hi @BerkayÇİLOĞLU, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

> Sql error number: 100090. Error Message: Updating a distribution key column in a MERGE statement is not supported.

`You got this error because updating a distribution key column through MERGE command is not supported in azure synapse currently.`

**The MERGE is currently in preview for Azure Synapse Analytics**.

You can refer to the official documentation for more details about this as given below: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true***

It clearly states that ***The MERGE command in Azure Synapse Analytics, which is presently in preview, may under certain conditions, leave the target table in an inconsistent state, with rows placed in the wrong distribution, causing later queries to return wrong results in some cases.***